# NodeMCU datatype String size

Tags: string, memory, lua, nodemcu

How much a String take size from heap ?

I did the following :-

- `node.heap()` it was 1000
- `k = "e"`
- `node.heap()` becomes 924

The variable took 72 byte of heap ?

Shouldn't it be [1 byte of variable value] + [other bytes like variable name, address, availability, length] and all of these will not exceed 10 bytes ?

Or its due to [fragmentation](http://node.heap()) of node.heap() ?

Will it take less heap if K was initialized before program execution as `k = ""` and in runtime I put the value in `k'

> NodeMCU info : Lua 5.1.4,   SDK 2.2.1,  ESP8266 12F

Comment: Yes, 72 bytes.  Lua has very good appetite for heap memory  :-)   Actually, you've created two new strings: "k" and "e".  Try with local variable "k" instead of global.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  local took 32 bytes, 32 is good for local, but this 72 is high xD

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'm not sure about that. Both "k" and "e" are constants and should be created at load time ...

Comment: On a 32 bit machine, a 2 byte string should take around 18 bytes: the sizes of a pointer, 3 bytes, an unsigned int, and a size_t, all rounded to the alignment of the pointer, plus 2 bytes of actual string data.

Comment: @siffiejoe u made me realize something, i edited my answer... will it take less heap if k was init before runtime, I think it will be in the flash until i change its value then become in memory !?

Comment: @siffiejoe - You are correct.  [Proof](https://pastebin.com/3gtaxRu2).  Maybe OP works in something like a REPL?